# Is there a way to run resource monitor (resmon.exe) without administrator privileges?

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator, uac, resource-monitor

Is there a way to run resource monitor (resmon.exe) without administrator privileges?

The user is member of the debug users, power users, performance monitor and performance log groups, however, this does not seem enough, he is still getting no data and an "access denied" message when trying to start logging

Comment: Had you really wanted them to not have admin privileges or just not need an admin to enter their credentials?

Comment: The user (and if possible, the resource monitor process) should not have admin privileges at all.

Answer (score 3):

As Resource Monitor displays live statistics on network-traffic and open files and tasks of ALL users, it needs access to that Information. This access requires admin access.

So, the answer is: no it's not possible for the Process to not have admin rights.

What you CAN do however, is to set up a (sheduled) task, that the user is allowed to start. that task in turn, could start the res mon. So the user can start the ressource monitor without requireing adminrights, and he also can't do other stuff with the rights (apart from the options resmon.exe gives him, like stopping/starting tasks ...)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Would love a little more detail on this answer, even just a link to a general guide for setting up scheduled tasks and allowing specific users to run them....

Comment: @Wildcard, actually I just found the answer to that in another superuser.com question: http://superuser.com/questions/402070/run-task-scheduler-task-on-demand-from-limited-user-account-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Solution proposed by T3rminat0r is not gonna work. Only works for tasks running silently in the background. But original poster required to run an exe with a GUI.

It can be solved, however, using [surun](http://kay-bruns.de/wp/software/surun/) with a rule as in this screenshot:

[image: this screenshot]

Comment: Interesting. Is there an English version of that tool? A screenshot with English text would be preferable, since this is an English-only site.

Comment: Did not work for me on Windows 10 Pro 21H2, unfortunately. 
Is it because of me being too stupid or did it really stop working since a certain Windows version?